# Restarting setInterval after clearInterval in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

In this game I'm building, I clear the setInterval after the user loses. When they click Play Again? I want the timer to start again, but I'm having trouble making that happen while using React. I've tried several things like separating the timer into its own component, making a helper function, and using the life cycle methods, but I just can't seem to get this part. I can start and clear the setInterval just fine, but it's restarting it that's my problem here.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// helper function to set a random action
function setRandomAction() {
    let actions = ['bop it', 'pull it', 'twist it'];
    let rando = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)];
    return rando;
}
class BopIt extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // set initial action in this.state so it is not empty on pageload
        this.state = {
            action: setRandomAction(),
            countdown: 3,
            userPressed: '',
            play: true
        }
        this.bind = this.keyPressed.bind(this);
        this.bind = this.keepPlaying.bind(this);
        this.bind = this.timer.bind(this);
        this.bind = this.startTimer.bind(this);
        this.bind = this.endGame.bind(this);
        this.quitGame = this.quitGame.bind(this);
        this.playAgain = this.playAgain.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyPressed();
        this.startTimer();
    }
    startTimer() {
        let setTimerTime = parseInt(`${this.state.countdown - 2}000`);
        this.stopIntervalId = setInterval(() => this.timer(), setTimerTime);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.startTimer();
        this.keyPressed();
        this.keepPlaying();
        this.endGame();
    }

    timer() {
        var count = this.state.countdown;
        if (count === 0) {
            count = 4
        }
        this.setState({countdown: count - 1});
    }
    keyPressed() {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
                this.setState({
                    userPressed: 'pull it'
                });
            } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                this.setState({
                    userPressed: 'bop it'
                });
            } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
                this.setState({
                    userPressed: 'twist it'
                });
            } else {
                // this.endGame();
                this.setState({
                    userPressed: 'wrong'
                });
            }
            if (this.state.userPressed !== this.state.action) {
                this.endGame();
            } else {
                this.keepPlaying();
            }
        });
    }
    keepPlaying() {
        let actions = ['bop it', 'pull it', 'twist it'];
        let rando = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)];
        this.setState({
            action: rando,
            userPressed: ''
        });
    }
    endGame() {
        console.log('You Lost!!!');
        this.setState({
            play: false
        });
    }
    quitGame() {
        clearInterval(this.stopIntervalId);
    }
    playAgain() {
        this.setState({
            play: true,
            action: setRandomAction(),
            countdown: 3
        });
    }
    render() {
        // if (this.state.countdown <= 0) {
        //   this.endGame();
        // }
        console.log(this.state)
        let gameAction = `${this.state.action} ${this.state.countdown}`;
        return (
          <div className="bop-it">
            <div className="show-action">
            {this.state.play ?  gameAction : <ResetGame playAgain={this.playAgain} quitGame={this.quitGame}/> }
            </div>
            <span>Pull It</span>
              <br/>
            <span>Bop It</span>
              <br/>
            <span>Twist It</span>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
class ResetGame extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="button" value="Play Again?" onClick={this.props.playAgain}/>
            <input type="button" value="Quit Game?" onClick={this.props.quitGame}/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
export default BopIt
```

EDIT:

I ended up simply calling `this.startTimer()` at the end of the `playAgain()` method. I could have sworn I did that previously, but apparently not. I'm also making sure to only call `clearInterval` in one place so there are no conflicts in other parts of the app. 
Another issue I was having was that whenever I got `setInterval` to restart, the timer was counting down at a faster rate. That was because of this:
`` let setTimerTime = parseInt(`${this.state.countdown - 2}000`);
this.stopIntervalId = setInterval(() => this.timer(), setTimerTime); ``

I put that line of code there because I eventually want the user to choose the game speed, but this was totally messing up the `countdown` property in my app's state object. Removing this line for now has cleared up some confusion too.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// helper function to set a random action
function setRandomAction() {
  let actions = ['bop it', 'pull it', 'twist it'];
  let rando = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)];

  return rando;
}

class BopIt extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // set initial action in this.state so it is not empty on pageload
    this.state = {
      action: setRandomAction(),
      countdown: 3,
      userPressed: '',
      play: true
    }
    this.bind = this.keyPressed.bind(this);
    this.bind = this.keepPlaying.bind(this);
    this.bind = this.endGame.bind(this);
    this.bind = this.timer.bind(this);
    this.bind = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.quitGame = this.quitGame.bind(this);
    this.playAgain = this.playAgain.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyPressed();
    this.startTimer();
  }
  startTimer() {
    // let setTimerTime = parseInt(`${this.state.countdown - 2}000`);
    this.stopIntervalId = setInterval(() => this.timer(), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyPressed();
    this.keepPlaying();
    this.endGame();
  }
  timer() {
    let count = this.state.countdown;
    if (count === 0) {
      count = 4
      // end the game if the timer hits 0
      this.endGame();
    }
    this.setState({countdown: count - 1});
  }
  keyPressed() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
        this.setState({
          userPressed: 'pull it'
        });
      } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        this.setState({
          userPressed: 'bop it'
        });
      } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
        this.setState({
          userPressed: 'twist it'
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          userPressed: 'wrong'
        });
      }
      // if user presses wrong key, then the game is over
      if (this.state.userPressed !== this.state.action) {
        this.endGame();
      } else {
        // otherwise, reset the time and chooose a random action
        this.keepPlaying();
      }
    });
  }

  keepPlaying() {
    this.setState({
      action: setRandomAction(),
      countdown: 3,
      userPressed: ''
    });
  }
  endGame() {
    console.log('You Lost!!!');
    this.setState({
      play: false
    });
    clearInterval(this.stopIntervalId);
  }
  quitGame() {
    // clearInterval(this.stopIntervalId);
    console.log('you have left the game')
  }
  playAgain() {
    this.setState({
      play: true,
      action: setRandomAction(),
      countdown: 3
    });
    this.startTimer();
  }
  render() {
    let gameAction = `${this.state.action} ${this.state.countdown}`;
    return (
      <div className="bop-it">
        <div className="show-action">
        {this.state.play ?  gameAction :
          <ResetGame
            playAgain={this.playAgain}
            quitGame={this.quitGame}
          />
        }
        </div>
        <span>Pull It</span>
          <br/>
        <span>Bop It</span>
          <br/>
        <span>Twist It</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class ResetGame extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="Play Again?" onClick={this.props.playAgain}/>
        <input type="button" value="Quit Game?" onClick={this.props.quitGame}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BopIt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are setting 2 timers, at the same time, one in `componentWillUnmount` and another one in `componentWillMount` and when you delete them you only delete one of them because the other gets lost by variable overwritting

I would change the following methods on your code, so that it's a little more difficult to create duplicate timers and so that it also triggers the timer again after playing again

```
startTimer() {
    let setTimerTime = parseInt(`${this.state.countdown - 2}000`);
    if (!this.stopIntervalId) {
        this.stopIntervalId = setInterval(() => this.timer(), setTimerTime);
    }
}
quitGame() {
    clearInterval(this.stopIntervalId);
    this.stopIntervalId = undefined;
}
playAgain() {
    this.setState({
        play: true,
        action: setRandomAction(),
        countdown: 3
    });
    this.startTimer()
}
```

Comment: I se what you're saying, and that definitely could've been an issue. I haven't found any good examples that explain the life cycle methods of React just yet (that make sense to me), so knowing how to use `componentWillUnmount` and `componentWillMount` is still something I'm wrapping my head around. You can see my edit above for how I resolved the issue.

Comment: I did on my original answer also add the call to the `startTimer()` at the end of the `playAgain` method (I did say that the methods I added on the question were the ones I would modify because they had missing logic or information), it would be nice that you would give me some upvote for that, because it would have also helped you.